# Reactjs renders blank page on removing unused firebase config import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am using Firebase for my ReactJS web app. I have the **FirebaseConfig.js** file in my project.
I imported this config file in one of the components in order to use the firebase auth feature and everything was working perfectly. 
But later, while doing some refactoring I removed the firebase related code which left an *Unused import of FirebaseConfig*.

Point to be noted is that, while the unused import is still present, I saved the project and everything was same. Now the problem arises, if I remove that *unused import*, save and run the project in browser, I see a blank page without any error in the console and on inspecting the element it showed empty `<div>` in the `<body>` tag.

Tried to debug this issue and came to the conclusion that this particular *unused import* has to be present in any of the components for the browser to render the project.

Please share your views on this really weird bug.

(I am Using VS Code)

**EDIT:**

(Hope these makes the question more clear)

**Screenshot showing the unused import in question:**

[image: Screenshot showing the unused import in question]

**Content showing in the browser with a warning in console clearly showing the presence of unused import:**

[image: Result in browser with unused import]

**Result in browser after removing the unused import. Blank page without any warning in console:**

[image: Result in browser without unused import]

**The usual FirebaseConfig file**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCxMlMsmPAZNM_6g7gavsyYUf4GW1v7HsE",
    authDomain: "physionext-d454f.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://physionext-d454f.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "physionext-d454f",
    storageBucket: "physionext-d454f.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "819439708505",
    appId: "1:819439708505:web:fb68d9fb012fc0493d4448",
    measurementId: "G-D2LM519RXX"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  export default firebase;
```

**index.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider,useSelector  } from 'react-redux';
import { getFirebase, ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, isLoaded } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import { createFirestoreInstance, getFirestore, reduxFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
    reduxFirestore(firebase)
  )
);

const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true
};

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: rrfConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance
};

const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <Router>
        <AuthIsLoaded>
          <App />
        </AuthIsLoaded>
      </Router>
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>
);

function AuthIsLoaded({ children }) {
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.firebase.auth)
  console.log(auth)
  if (!isLoaded(auth)) return <div></div>;
  return children
}

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: you have to add your code for better understanding

Comment: Would be nice to have sandbox example. The problem is probably something silly. Are you using firebase elsewhere ? if I had to guess the problem is that you try access firebase before it gets initialized somewhere. And this "unused" import was solving that problem

Comment: Switching to react-redux-firebase might be a good idea.

Comment: @ErnestasButa I am actually using react-redux-firebase. The only other file where firebase is used currently is *index.js* file and your comment made me wonder that the cause of problem might be there. I am right now updating the question with index.js file.

Comment: In index you never initialize firebase.
check getting started page of react-redux-firebase

http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/getting_started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace in Index.js:

```
  import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

To:

```
import firebase from './FirebaseConfig';
```

Comment: This was a really stupid mistake. Even I just figured that out by myself after your last comment.

Comment: 9/10 times it's something silly like that :) Trust nothing :D